Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows Grub failed. Boot -Repair report's link in description
I had a issue with dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. After running Boot-Repair I have got this report, but I do not have any idea what to do with it.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cmPdYpgGvt/
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sda8,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount /dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sda8 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:712 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-76-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0000,2001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - USB DISK 3.0 (USB DISK 3.0)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x10,0x0)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x389f05b5,0x800,0x3a977c0)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 uname -r
5.15.0-76-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0000,2001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - USB DISK 3.0 (USB DISK 3.0)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x10,0x0)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x389f05b5,0x800,0x3a977c0)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda8 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-87-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-87-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-79-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-79-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32864 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/boot/bootx64.efi /efi/boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on sda8
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.15(15.15) from Insyde
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0000,2001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive (UEFI) - USB DISK 3.0 (USB DISK 3.0)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x10,0x0)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x389f05b5,0x800,0x3a977c0)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/Boot/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
0be1df45737df88d6a8c5e9ebd7a896d   sda1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   sda1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   sda1/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
1b89ce6e6ed9c195d61df80630b0465f   sda1/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
8561c3e35368c746fd3cf8b9c0e71663   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
8f87a2fbaaa64d7b22150e1881b9eb87   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda7    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda8    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda7    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda8    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda7    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda8    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0F5A1798-E54C-4676-8388-06E46AF1C134
          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1        2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
sda2      534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3      567296  419997695 419430400   200G Microsoft basic data
sda4   419997696  930498559 510500864 243.4G Microsoft basic data
sda5   930498560 1440999423 510500864 243.4G Microsoft basic data
sda6  1440999424 1472249855  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
sda7  1951504384 1953511423   2007040   980M Windows recovery environment
sda8  1472249856 1951504383 479254528 228.5G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x389f05b5
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 61439935 61437888 29.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD10SPZX-60Z:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:215GB:215GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:215GB:476GB:261GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:476GB:738GB:261GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:738GB:754GB:16.0GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
8:754GB:999GB:245GB:ext4::;
7:999GB:1000GB:1028MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
sdb:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos: USB DISK 3.0:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL            PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
├─sda1 vfat     CA29-4C9C                            f04d6a15-d8d1-42ce-9300-58aa137c7ac9 SYSTEM           EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               b2a904dd-d223-4467-9490-28d8aca66c5e                  Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     C692487E924874C9                     ee5beef2-464e-4406-8d41-6dbdad379857 Windows          Basic data partition
├─sda4 ntfs     F23E58753E583537                     ddb8c8f1-5155-4b80-ab8d-700bc294ce1d                  Basic data partition
├─sda5 ntfs     0E40632D40631AAB                     a476340a-fbfa-45b7-9473-b2b1648c5db5                  Basic data partition
├─sda6 swap     69f75fe1-4dd2-47fe-994b-88d4a9cb5b80 47bdd33d-10e3-4923-a7f4-a4508cecaea8                  
├─sda7 ntfs     DA947E68947E46D3                     af98d6d9-ce43-4f5a-97fa-a684a3ea4931 Windows RE tools Basic data partition
└─sda8 ext4     e2e001c8-6cd5-4ada-80ca-fac7f1bab452 4e8767fb-3d12-4c33-847d-d3a44e8ede15                  
sdb                                                                                                        
└─sdb1 vfat     40A7-9887                            389f05b5-01                          BOOT-REPAIR      

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

            Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1   197.3M  23% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3   105.3G  47% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4     243G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sda5   243.1G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda7   461.8M  53% /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
/dev/sda8   163.6G  22% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
/dev/sdb1    26.8G   8% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1   vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda3   fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda4   fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda5   fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda7   fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda8   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1   vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid e2e001c8-6cd5-4ada-80ca-fac7f1bab452 root hd0,gpt8 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   e2e001c8-6cd5-4ada-80ca-fac7f1bab452
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-CA29-4C9C
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda8/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=e2e001c8-6cd5-4ada-80ca-fac7f1bab452 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=CA29-4C9C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=69f75fe1-4dd2-47fe-994b-88d4a9cb5b80 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda8/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda8: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 879.924884796 = 944.812150784  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 706.307689667 = 758.392107008  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-79-generic                 1
 879.924884796 = 944.812150784  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-87-generic                 1
 706.307689667 = 758.392107008  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 914.701808929 = 982.153588736  boot/initrd.img                                1
 914.249996185 = 981.668458496  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-79-generic              5
 914.701808929 = 982.153588736  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-87-generic              1
 914.249996185 = 981.668458496  boot/initrd.img.old                            5

===================== sda8: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Mar 30  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 21  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Mar 18  2019 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit
Start Boot-Repair-Disk 64-bit (compatibility mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
sprunge.us ko ()

